# Roxy Fileman and Virtual Directorys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, tinymce, roxy-fileman

I have a solution with 2 projects in, one called "admin", the other say "work" (an Umbraco instance)
 - Work has an images folder which contains the images for the site 
    banners/thumnails etc. 
 - Admin allows an admin user to add new stories, with images, using TinyMCE
   and the fileman plug in.

So in IIS I created a virtual folder in Admin which points to the images folder in work, however when I try and browse the folder in fileman it repeats lots of sub directoriers and doesnt display any images.And I cannot upload any images either, it just gives me an error.
The Files_Root entry is as follows within the conf.json file.

```
    "FILES_ROOT":          ".//images//",
```

So how do I get this virtual folder to work with fileman?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem as well - when the FILES_ROOT points to a virtual folder in IIS, the Fileman component chokes when trying to retrieve the list of files, and when uploading, and maybe some other places. The requests don't pass the folder location properly when it references a virtual directory. If you put a network sniffer on it, you'll see the requests sent to fileman/asp_net/main.ashx and the responses that come back with the error "The given path's format is not supported."

I've reported the bug to the author via the website, but I have also discovered that if you replace the virtual directory with a SYMLINK, everything seems to work.

If you have IIS access, you probably have command line access to create the symlink, which can be done as:

```
mklink /j "{virtual location within your website}" "{physical location}"
```

Both locations should be full paths, including drive letters and the "virtual" location should be in your website root.

So far, I have not seen an problems referencing files this way instead of with a virtual directory, other than that my site backups started including the files in the symlink, since the O/S sees that as a physical folder within the site now.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: It seems when I tried this that the returned directory paths are fully qualified, eg, it returns "C:\inetpub\..." etc.  It's returning the directory I set the symlink to.  Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You also can't create symbolic links to network shares, so if your virtual directories point at a file server/network path then this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not good for every situation (maybe not even for the user that asked the question), but figured I would share in case it might help someone trying to get virtual directories mapped to network shares working. I needed to modify the `ListDirTree` function in file `fileman/asp_net/main.ashx`

```
protected void ListDirTree(string type)
{
    string filesRoot = GetFilesRoot();
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo( filesRoot );
    if ( !d.Exists )
        throw new Exception( "Invalid files root directory. Check your configuration: " + filesRoot );

    ArrayList dirs = ListDirs( d.FullName );
    dirs.Insert( 0, d.FullName );

    string localPath = _context.Server.MapPath( "~/" );
    bool isLocal = filesRoot.Contains( ":" );
    _r.Write( "[" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < dirs.Count; i++ )
    {
        string dir = (string)dirs[i];
        string lPath;
        //If it is a local path, leave it as it was
        if ( isLocal )
            lPath = dir.Replace( localPath, "" ).Replace( "\\", "/" );
        else
            //Otherwise probably a virtual directory, put the original files_root location back
            lPath = dir.Replace( filesRoot, GetSetting( "FILES_ROOT" ) ).Replace( "\\", "/" );
        _r.Write( "{\"p\":\"/" + lPath + "\",\"f\":\"" + GetFiles( dir, type ).Count.ToString() + "\",\"d\":\"" + Directory.GetDirectories( dir ).Length.ToString() + "\"}" );
        if ( i < dirs.Count - 1 )
            _r.Write( "," );
    }
    _r.Write( "]" );
}
```